# when i try to end the tag automatically it close but with extra right angle tag "<h1/>>" in Vs code editor

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

Here in my vs code , i try to use self closing tag but it appear double right angle tag ">>"
how can i prevent the tag 
Thanks in advance

```
<h1></h1>>
<h2></h2>>
<h3></h3>>
```

Comment: Which extension you are using for this?

Comment: no extension right now  though i have use auto close tag extension but disabled it